# Append values of different variables

Tags: bash, shell, variables, echo

I am trying to append values of different variable

Eg:

```
p1=100
j=1
```

and

```
echo $p1
100
echo $j
1
```

but I append both the value I need out put as

```
echo $p$j
100
```

that means instead of 1, I will give `$j` which has the same value, is there any other option?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `${!var}` to refer to the value of the variable `var`:

```
$ var="p"$j
$ echo $var
p1
$ echo ${!var}
100
```

Comment: wow...awesome man...thanks...finally completed my script...:)

Comment: Nice to read that, @prabhu !